# Compiz don't work with Gnome Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, 17.04, 17.10

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 and Compiz + Compiz plugins.
For example:

- Enhanced Zoom Desktop
- Magnifier
- Negative
- Show Mouse
- etc.

After upgrading to 17.10 Compiz effect don't work.
Because Unity removed for 17.10.
Compiz and plugins installed and enabled but don't work.

How to fix it? Is it possible enable Compiz effects for Gnome?

For me without Compiz effect Gnome completely unusable. Because I have problems with eyes.

Comment: Just install and use unity. GNOME Shell has its own window manager, and doesn't use compiz, so compiz tweaks don't work. You might be able to find similar extensions: https://extensions.gnome.org

Comment: Most of the features you want should be available in *Settings > Universal Access*.

Comment: @pomsky "Universal Access" not support negative effects. Mouse zooming unusable - many lugs on the screen.